# This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.0.0 or above.

Tags: android

Well i m really fed up with this Error. ..
       I updated my SDK with 12 API and got this error. before updating everything is working fine. but after updating SDK i got java.lang.Object can not be resolved  and The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path then try building this project.
        Well i removed this error with the help of this link
http://dev-answers.blogspot.de/2009/06/eclipse-build-errors-javalangobject.html

but now I m getting android.os can not be resolved,R can not be resolved to a type..there are 100 errors.

please help me .....

Answer (score 0):

It simply means you need to update your Eclipse ADT Plugin.
here is a detailed instruction:
[Installing ADT](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)